# Assigning a Queue as the Owner of a Lead in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

I have a webform in Cloud Pages that, upon submission, will do a few things. One of those things is to update the Lead's Owner to be one of several different queues.

The relevant code:

```
SET @ownerID = "00G0L0000042FX7"
SET @salesforceUpdate = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("lead", LongSFID(@SubscriberKey),
                   "FirstName"                     , @FirstName, 
                   "LastName"                      , @LastName, 
                   "MobilePhone"                   , @Phone, 
                   "NVMConnect__NextContactTime__c", @NextContactTime, 
                   "Owner"                         , @ownerID)
```

The response when I catch the exception thrown is:

```
Call to update the salesforceobject lead ID = 00Q0L00001H6FE6UAN failed! Error status code: INVALID_FIELDError message: The external foreign key reference does not reference a valid entity: Owner
```

The `@ownerId` is definitely the ID of the queue
[image: image of url]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OwnerID is definitely the ID of the queue, then it must be column naming in the function call, I noticed you have `Owner` as the column name but it should be `OwnerId` according to the salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm).

```
SET @ownerID = "00G0L0000042FX7"
SET @salesforceUpdate = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("lead", LongSFID(@SubscriberKey),
               "FirstName"                     , @FirstName, 
               "LastName"                      , @LastName, 
               "MobilePhone"                   , @Phone, 
               "NVMConnect__NextContactTime__c", @NextContactTime, 
               "OwnerId"                         , @ownerID)
```

Here is a screenshot from the documentation for proof

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help!